# PHP mailing - sender address

Tags: php, email, sender

I have script form on my website that looks like this:

```
 `
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 $mailto = "biuro@tlumaczgdanski.pl";  //My email address
 //getting customer data

 $fromEmail = $_POST['email']; //getting customer email
 $phone = $_POST['tel']; //getting customer Phome number
 $subject = $_POST['subject']; //getting subject line from client
 $subject2 = "Tłumacz Gdański - Potwierdzenia otrzymania wiadomości"; // For customer confirmation

 //Email body I will receive
 $message = "Wiadomość ze strony www"  . "\n\n"
 . "Wiadomość Klienta: " . "\n" . $_POST['message'] . "\n\n" . "Telefon: " . $phone . "\n" . "Email: " .  $fromEmail;

 //Message for client confirmation
 $message2 = "Dziękujemy za nadesłaną wiadomość!"  . "\n"
 . "Odpowiemy najszybiej jak to tylko możliwe" . "\n\n"
 . "Nadesłana wiadomość: " . "\n" . $_POST['message'] . "\n\n"
 . "Pozdrawiamy," . "\n" . " Tłumacz Gdański!" . "\n\n" . "  biuro@tlumaczgdanski.pl";

 //Email headers
 $headers = "Od: " . $fromEmail; // Client email, I will receive
 $headers2 = "Od: " . $mailto; // This will receive client

 //PHP mailer function

  $result1 = mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $headers); // This email sent to My address
  $result2 = mail($fromEmail, $subject2, $message2, $headers2); //This confirmation email to client

  //Checking if Mails sent successfully

  if ($result1 && $result2) {
    $success = "Your Message was sent Successfully!";
  } else {
    $failed = "We are sorry. Message couldn't be delivered";
  }

}

?>
`
```

And it should display "biuro@tlumaczgdanski.pl" in sender place in mailbox but it shows that it was send from example = "serwer2147189@serwer2147189.hosting.pl"

Is there a way to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you can use "Od"? Did you try with "From"?

Comment: @FilipMüller thank you, this works. 
Please add this as an answer so I could give you acceptance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace "Od:" with its English equivalent "From:". Email headers only understand English.